# Sum of two $n$th powers in finite fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, finite-fields, additive-combinatorics

Let $q$ be a prime power, let $n$ be a positive integer and let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be the finite field of cardinality $q$. I have some computational evidence that the set $$\{x^n+(-1)^nay^n:x,y\in\mathbb{F}_q\}$$ is the whole of $\mathbb{F}_q$, unless $q$ is small (with respect to $n$).

This does make sense because if, for instance, $q-1=n$, then the set
$\{ x^n+(-1)^nay^n:x,y\in\mathbb{F}_q \}$ only consists of $\{0,1,a,1+a\}$ because each element of $\mathbb{F}_q$ raised to the $n$ equals either $0$ or $1$.

Can anyone justify the computational evidence?

Comment: Don't you want $a \ne 0$?

Comment: You should say what is $a$ (it should be an element that makes sense in every $\mathbf{F}_q$), so maybe a nonzero integer?

Comment: Replace $y$ with $-y$ to get rid of the $(-1)^n$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, this is true, and is proved e.g. as Corollary 3 of Small's "[Diagonal equations over large finite fields](https://doi.org/10.4153/CJM-1984-016-6)" (Can. J. Math. 1984).

Small actually gives explicit bounds on how large $q$ needs to be in terms of $n$ — in particular the equation $ax^n+by^n$ generates all of $\mathbb{F}_q$ whenever $a,b\in\mathbb{F}_q\setminus\{0\}$ and $q>(\delta-1)^4$, where $\delta=(n,q-1)$.

Comment: I think results along these lines go back to Schur. See, e.g., https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2089070/fermats-last-theorem-over-finite-fields

Comment: For small $n$ ($n\le 4$) this goes back to Gauss :)

Answer (score 4):

I would like to give some comments and context, but I am not going to cite any improvement to the result of Small [quoted](https://mathoverflow.net/a/430496) by Thomas Bloom. (I do not know if there is any.)

Since the image of $f(x)=x^n$ is the same as that of $g(x)=x^{\gcd(q-1,n)}$, and $\gcd(q-1,n)$ divides $q-1$, we may restrict from now on to $n$ being a divisor of $q-1$.

You ask whether $f(x)+af(y)=z$ is solvable for each $z$. Since $f(0)=0$ we may assume $z\neq 0$.

Since the multiplicative group of a finite field is cyclic, the image of $f$ has size $1+((q-1)/n)$. This leads to two immediate results:

1. If $(1+((q-1)/n))^2<q$, which translates to $n>\sqrt{q}+1$, the answer is negative by a trivial counting argument (bounding the possible values of $z$ by the Cartesian product of the images of $f$).
2. If $2(1+((q-1)/n)>q$, which translates to $n=1,2$, for any given choice of $z$ the coset $z+\operatorname{Im}f$ intersects the subgroup $-\operatorname{Im}f$, hence the answer is positive in this case.

Gauss was highly interested in the number of solutions to $f(x)+f(y)=1$ for $n=3,4$. You can read about it in Chapter 8 of Ireland and Rosen's book "[A classical introduction to modern number theory](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4757-2103-4)", where Theorem 2 is due to Gauss. One can use Gauss sums and Jacobi sums to derive the estimate $\#\{x,y: f(x)+af(y)=z\}=q+E$ for $\lvert E\rvert\le n-1+\sqrt{q}(n-1)(n-2)$, which ensures a solution for each $z$ if $\sqrt[4]{q}+1>n$, which matches Small's result. See Proposition 8.4.1 for a special case (corresponding to $a=z=1$ and $q$ a prime) of this which contains all the ideas already. See also Theorem 5 in the aforementioned chapter for a general theorem of Weil from 1949 about diagonal hypersurfaces and the number of points on them; this inspired his famous Weil Conjectures.

See also the paper "[Sums of Powers in Large Finite Fields: A Mix of Methods](https://doi.org/10.1080/00029890.2021.1943117)" by
Vitaly Bergelson, Andrew Best and Alex Iosevich, that appeared in 2021 in the American Mathematical Monthly. It discusses all of the above and more, including Small's work and Schur's work [mentioned](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430492/sum-of-two-nth-powers-in-finite-fields#comment1107716_430496) by Gerry Myerson.